# Silence NGINX in Docker Compose

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker-compose

How can I silence NGINX in the terminal window while using Docker-Compose?  Every single call is being echoed to the console.  It is so noisy that I cannot see the other `console.log()` messages from Node.

Here's my `nginx.conf` file...

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 4096; }

http {

  ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout   30m;

  proxy_temp_path       /var/tmp;
  include               mime.types;
  default_type          application/octet-stream;
  sendfile              on;

  upstream mycompany-api01 {
    server mycompany-api01:3000;
  }

    server {
      listen        80;
      server_name   api01.mycompany.com;
      root          /var/www/public;

      location / {
          proxy_pass            http://mycompany-api01;
          proxy_http_version    1.1;
          proxy_set_header      Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header      Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header      Host $host;
          proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header      X-NginX-Proxy    true;
          proxy_cache_bypass    $http_upgrade;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `access_log off;` to only disable the access log and leave the error log on.

Or if you only don't want to see the logs you can use `docker-compose logs -f node` to only see the logs of node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [logging](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logging)

```
logging:
    driver: none
```

Comment: I would go with this one too